# Integer score to letter grade in C?

Tags: c

This program should be really easy but for some reason I can't figure out how to rework the logic so that it uses 'if' statements only (no else).

Basically it is like this

```
if(score >= 90)
grade = 'A';
else if(score >= 80)
grade = 'B';
```

etc

We are meant to rework this logic so that it uses only 'if' and not 'else'. I've tried a few ways and none of them seem to work for me. The way I tried which I thought would work is this

```
if(score <= 100)
{
    if(score < 90)
    {
        if(score <80)
        {
            if(score <70)
            {
                if(score <60)
                {
                    grade = 'F';
                }
                grade = 'D';
            }
            grade = 'C';
        }
        grade = 'B';
    }
}
if(score >= 90)
    grade = 'A';
```

This will get the grade of A correctly, and B but when I go below 80, it always gives me B. Can anyone point out my error? Or perhaps and easier way to do this?

Comment: Please compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`), e.g. to run your program step by step. It is an essential skill to have.

Comment: There are no bugs, it just doesn't give the correct result for the entered value if it is below 80.

Comment: But not giving the expected result *is* a bug (and most bugs are likewise)!

Comment: fall to the next statement.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch How does this function (or debugger, or whatever it is sorry I am new to C) know that it will give me the wrong answer? And how exactly do I use it?

Comment: Once you reach to the innner most if statement, you have to come back and on the way your grade variable is getting updated.

Comment: @AbhishekChoubey OH! Doh, thanks for that. I've got a working method now but it's nice to know what I was doing wrong in the first place.

Comment: You need to study and learn how to use debuggers. Read some [GDB tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/gdbtutorial.html); they are not magical tools, but enable you to follow step by step your program's execution. Debugging requires intelligence (e.g. because of [undecidability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) of the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem))

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out on my own before you guys posted, but I appreciate the help! I'm posting this as an answer cuz I did it differently then the two answers posted.

```
if(score < 60)
grade = 'F';
if(score >= 60)
grade = 'D';
if(score >=70)
grade = 'C';
if(score >=80)
grade = 'B';
if(score >= 90)
grade = 'A';
```

Basically just took the if-else logic and flipped it upside down without the else's. Thanks again!

Comment: Note that first if is not really needed, grade = 'F' is enough. I don't know whether it is a common rule, but personally I tend to leave "else" branch unnamed in cases where it is pure "else". Imagine `double score` and NAN value, for example.

Comment: `else if` would be better than separated `if`s like this

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities (nested and not):

```
grade = 'A';
if(score < 90)
{
    grade = 'B';
    if(score < 80)
    {
        grade = 'C';
        //...
    }
}


if(score >= 90) grade = 'A';
if(score >= 80 && score < 90) grade = 'B';
if(score >= 70 && score < 80) grade = 'C';
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the If statements

```
if(score < 90)
{grade = 'B';}
if(score <80)
{grade = 'C';}
if(score <70)
{grade = 'D';}
if(score <60)
{grade = 'F';}


if(score >= 90)
grade = 'A';
```

Comment: this is inefficient, like when score < 60 then you need to gl into all the if blocks and unnecessarily assign `grade` 4 times

Answer (score 0):

Always check from the smallest range up and compare with `<`/`<=`, or check from the maximum range down with `>`/`>=`. Besides use `else if` to avoid redundant checks like most of the above answers. For example OP's solution compares score with 60 twice, which is unnecessary

```
if (score < 60)
    grade = 'F';
else if (score < 70)
    grade = 'D';
else if (score < 80)
    grade = 'C';
else if (score < 90)
    grade = 'B';
else
    grade = 'A';
```

But you don't actually need that many `if` blocks

```
const char* SCORE[] = "FDCBA";
if (score < 60)
    grade = 'F'; // or = SCORE[0];
else if (score < 100);
    grade = SCORE[score/10 - 5];
else if (score == 100)
    grade = 'A'; // or = SCORE[4];
```